# How to scale ModelInstance in place

Tags: 3d, libgdx, transformation

I try to scale an object of type ModelInstance in libgdx, so that it does not change its position, but only scaling.
From my understanding, I have to move it to origin, scale it there and then move it back to it's original position.

Here is my code

```
            Vector3 tmp;
            curInstance.transform.getTranslation(tmp);
            curInstance.transform.translate(-tmp.x, -tmp.y, -tmp.z);
            curInstance.transform.scale(scalingFactor, scalingFactor, scalingFactor);
            curInstance.transform.translate(tmp);
            curInstance.calculateTransforms();
```

Apparently the line 
`curInstance.transform.getTranslation(tmp);`
does not do what I expect it to do, namely retrieve the current position/offset from the origin. `tmp` stays `(0, 0, 0)` after it.
What I get is the object scaling, but also moving towards center when scaling down, or away from the center, when scaling up. 
Another problem is that the lighting is wrong when I apply the scaling this way, as if some normals were invalid. But it looks fine, if I scale the meshes like

`for (Mesh m : instance.model.meshes) {m.scale(...)}`

except they are scaled relative to world's origin then.

I initialize the mesh like this

```
  mesh = new Mesh(true,faceIndices.length*3, altindices.length*3, new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"), new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal,3, "a_normal"));`,
```

then calculate the vertices coordinates, then do

```
  modelBuilder.begin();
  modelBuilder.part("mesh", mesh, GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.DARK_GRAY)));
  instance = modelBuilder.end();`
```

So my question: in libgdx, how can I scale an object of type ModelInstance?

Comment: `transform.getTranslation` will only give you the translation if you actually translated the transform earlier in code (e.g. `transform.translate(x, y, z)`, `transform.trn(x, y, z)`, `transform.setTranslation(x, y, z)` etc.). Note that the origin is always at (0,0,0), which is commonly the center of the model, but depends on the origin on which you modeled it.

Comment: @Xoppa is there a way to scale a model instance again its own origin then?
I create a modelInstance from mesh, and mesh is created from vertexArrays with giver coordinates.

Comment: It is by default scaled relative to its own origin.

Comment: @Xoppa then I must have messed somewhere else. Thanks for clarification. I have added the instance initialization code to the question.

Comment: I´m having the exact same problem. Did you find any solution to it?